# How do I stub android.os classes in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, real-time, stub, android-looper

I've written a [real-time subsystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625120/desktop-library-for-testing-a-real-time-android-app) for Android that I'd like to test on the desktop. I would like to run tests via a command line tool of my creation. The subsystem depends on Android as follows:

- android.os.Looper
- android.os.Handler (including Handler.Callback)
- android.os.Message
- android.util.Log

I need to stub these classes. [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) stubs these classes but [apparently doesn't allow for custom instances of Looper](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1993). Unless someone can point me to functional stubs, I plan to write them myself. I'd rather avoid the complexity of writing a test harness for a full Android emulator.

How do I get Android Studio to use my stubs for these classes in my tool build? I don't want to modify the subsystem to dynamically receive the classes it should use, out of fear of limiting optimization or making code unnecessarily messy. (But I am open to wrapping android.util.Log.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dépends on how you've implemented the use of the libraries listed. You can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249744/not-able-to-stub-post-method-of-android-os-handler-class for some hints.

Comment: Okay thanks. Looks like there might be a solution with `@MockInjects`, if Mockito doesn't impose too much of a framework. Looking into it, but I'd still love a direct answer!

Comment: Ha! I've thought of a better approach: don't use Android Studio. Duh!